# Objective C NSFetch Request

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to understanding using fetch requests in core data. I would like to make a fetch request to select a `Chord` entity from core data.

```
@interface ChordViewController ()

@property NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest;
@property NSEntityDescription* entityDescription;
@property NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext;

@end

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    self.fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    self.entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Chord" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [self.fetchRequest setEntity:self.entityDescription];
}
return self;
```

Is the fetch request reusable, and if so, is it good practice to reuse the same fetch request between fetches such that is it a class member property? I would also like to know if the entityDescription should be a class member property too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch requests and entity descriptions can be reused, but the cost of creation is relatively low so recreating isn't much of an issue. Predicates are more costly to recreate if you use any.

I assume your code is just typed in as creating a managed object context like that won't work (it has no connection to a persistent store...).

Comment: I will be passing a pointer to the ManagedObjectContext through AppDelegate. Should I do this with the constructor for my controller or simply set the pointer with ```self.chordViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;```. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the property is more normal. If you're concerned about correctness, the AppDelegate shouldn't be creating the Core Data stack (persistent store coordinator / MOC ...)

Comment: Ah right! This seems to be the behaviour by default in a new iOS app created through Xcode. How would you structure it?

Comment: I would use a singleton data controller. Some people would say that isn't correct either. But some data controller anyway (even if created by the root view controller and the reference passed around the other view controllers when pushed).